# Passing Puppeteer page as params in a function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, jquery-selectors, puppeteer

## Intro

The `loginLinkedin` takes me to the login page and then return for me the puppeteer page which is then assigned to root so I can still have more options do work with it.

`const root = await loginToLInkined("https://www.linkedin.com/login");`

```
    await root.goto(url);
    max_page = await getMaxPage(root);
    console.log("max page",max_page)
```

I then `goto(url)`

`url` is another page I need to go to.

after that I call the `getMaxPage(root)` with root as a param so I can `evaluate()` in that function

### Problem

```
const getMaxPage = async root => {
  const maxPage = await root.evaluate(()=> {
    return document.querySelector(
      "li.artdeco-pagination__indicator:nth-last-Child(1)"
    );
  });
  console.log(maxPage)
  return parseInt(maxPage.innerText);
};
```

The problem is that when I console.log(maxPage) it returns undefined and I realized that adding a root s a param isn't actually working the way I'm supposed to do.

What am I doing wrong and how it properly done.

#### Note I have actually tried to root.evaluate without adding a function and adding the root as a param and it actually returned for me the `maxpage`

Comment: Try moving the innerText inside of the evaluate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in *what* you return from `page.evaluate()`:

```
const maxPage = await root.evaluate(()=> {
    return document.querySelector(
      "li.artdeco-pagination__indicator:nth-last-Child(1)"
    );
});
```

This is a DOM node, which is a complex object that cannot be [serialized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description), and the return value **must be** serializable in order to be returned back to node from Chromium.

So to fix that and all the future scripts just return only what is needed and what can be `JSON.stringify`ed without error. As pguardiario correctly noted in the comment, in this case it's enough to return `innerText` from that node:

```
const maxPage = await root.evaluate(()=> {
  return document.querySelector("li.artdeco-pagination__indicator:nth-last-Child(1)").innerText;
});
```

Comment: I like to call them "Node Context" and "Browser Context", to explain a bit better. :D

Comment: I do too! But for this question I felt like it's more important to... say, *visualize* where the data goes from to.